# can i install fashion mnist on older version of tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm working in tensorflow 1.4.0 and I want to use fashion_mnist datasets. I know that this version does not have this datasets, but there is a way to have this?

Comment: Did you check: [Machine Learning Meets Fashion](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-meets-fashion-48ee8f6541ad)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution here: [Fashion-MNIST](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist)

You can download the data that you find in the link above and placed it in data/fashion.

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
data = input_data.read_data_sets('data/fashion')

data.train.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```

Or passing in a source url to the read_data_sets:

```
data = input_data.read_data_sets('data/fashion', source_url='http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/')
```